# Equivalent of browseable = no in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-sharing, server-message-block, smbfs

What's the equivalent of the smb.conf setting `browsable = no` in Windows?

It's not just adding a $ to the share name to make it a hidden share.

Running

```
net view \\server /all
```

on a for a Linux share on `\\server` does NOT list shares where `browsable = no`, whereas on Windows, it DOES include administrative/hidden shares (C$, IPC$, etc)

Comment: As there appears to be some confusion what `browseable` in the samba configuration is: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html#BROWSEABLE

Comment: So do you know if there is a way to do that in Windows??

Answer (score 0):

Listing the shares (which is what you're doing with that net view command) and browsing the shares aren't the same thing. Hidden shares aren't browse-able.

That net view command tells the server to **list** all of it's shares. That doesn't mean they are browse-able on the network. They aren't. The $ hides them.

Comment: So how do I disable listing them in Windows? That's what browsable no is doing

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why do you not want them listed?

Comment: File server is multi tenant and one user shouldn't see shares they don't have access to. Have tried ABE but it slows down large folders too much

Answer (score -2):

Let us take an example Runas command, you can have a control on this command by applying policies.  This command can be disabled on local as well as remote system.

Runas command is executed in Windows Command Processor located in system32.  There are so many commands such as dir, mkdir, cd, cls, etc these commands are not found as a file in system32, but whenever you execute them in Windows Command Processor they run as if there were some files related to them, in fact there is no such file in system32, just command console who is responsible for these commands to run on your system.

I hope you understand.

Comment: Really not helpful at all